# block.coinbase on Polygon

Tags: solidity, polygon

I noticed a problem while interacting with a contract that relies on `block.coinbase` for some of its logic. The contract keeps reverting with `execution reverted: ERC721: mint to the zero address`. It was deployed to Polygon Mainnet. Should `block.coinbase` not be used in Solidity contracts deployed to Polygon? Is there a way to make the contract work after deploying?